# Matlab arrays operation

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays, a and b, of different size. Each one contains unique values.

I want to compare both and if any value of array a is in array b, then I want to delete it from b (e.g. `a = [2 3 5]`, `b = [1 8 6 2 3 7]`, results `b = [1 8 6 7]`).

How can it be implemented in Matlab?

Answer (score 7):

Use `setdiff` to find elements in one set but not the other.

```
setdiff(b, a)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `intersect` with 3 output arguments to get the indices of the elements to be deleted:

```
[c, ia, ib] = intersect(a, b);
b (ib) = [];
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option is to use the [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) function to remove elements from `b` that are members of `a` via [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
b(ismember(b,a)) = [];
```