# How to get the elements from one vector that aren't in another vector

Tags: matlab

I know this is simple but am having a hard time finding the right function for this.  I have a vector `a = [1 2 3 4]` and another vector `b = [1 2 6 8]`.  I want to return all of the elements in `a` that aren't in `b`.  In this case, it would be `[3 4]`.  How do you do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab arrays operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802276/matlab-arrays-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try with [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.it/help/techdoc/ref/setdiff.html)?

```
c = setdiff(a,b)
```