# Find the elements in an array that is not in another array

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays lets say A = [1;2;4;7;10;20];
B = [1;4;8];

Now I want to find the elements of A, that are not in B i.e; [2;7;10;20]. I just need their index that is the index of the elements [2;7;10;20] in A. How can I implement this in matlab. I can use loops and all. But that is not what I want. I want an elegant solution. Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab arrays operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802276/matlab-arrays-operation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that using the `ismember` function.

```
A = [1;2;4;7;10;20]; 
B = [1;4;8];
ismem = ismember(A,B);
```

will give you

```
[1 0 1 0 0 0]'
```

If you really need the indices, you can use `find`.

```
find(ismem==0)
```

Just as a reminder, you can always use logical indexing like so:

```
A(~ismem)
```

will give you

```
[2 7 10 20]'
```

Comment: [TF,LOC] = ismember(A,S) for the array A returns an array of the same size as A containing 1 where the elements of A are in the set S and 0 otherwise. The indices for the matching are provided in LOC that contains the highest absolute index in S for each element in A which is a member of S and 0 if there is no such index.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the elements of A which are not in B you can use [setdiff](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html).

`setdiff(A,B)` gives `[2; 7; 10; 20]` (vector A with elements in B removed)

If you want the indices of the elements rather than their values, you can use [ismember](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/ordinal.ismember.html) and negate the result.

Answer (score 3):

Check out `setxor`:

[C, ia, ib] = setxor(A, B)

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setxor.html) is the Mathworks page. You will want `ia` for the indexes of those that are in A but not B.