# How to remove specific values from a vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

If I have for example the following vector of indices:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 ... 4997 4998 4999 5000]
```

How can I remove indices in X specified by another vector such as

```
Y = [9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 ... 981 990 999]
```

So that after the deletion X would be:

```
X = [1 ... 8 10 ... 17 19 ... 26 28 ... etc]
```

Another example would be `A = [1 2 3 4 5] and B = [2 5]`

so that `A-B = [1 3 4]`

Thank you for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab arrays operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802276/matlab-arrays-operation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
C=setdiff(A, B);
```